# Android wearablelistenerservice not listening when phone asleep

Tags: android, service, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, sleep-mode

I have a small home automation application running on my phone which listens for the 'command' from a wearable and sends a get request.

When the phones screen is on (i.e. the device is awake) these messages are received by my WearableListenerService however when the phone goes to sleep the messages are not passed from the Wear device to the phone.

If I send a message from the wearable to the phone when the phone is asleep, and then I wake up the phone manually within the message timeout period, the message is received and the get request subsequently fired.

I was wondering if there is any way to keep the WearableListenerService listening even when the device is locked, I am aware of WakeLocks but these seem to be terrible for battery life.

I am struggling to see if this is the defined behaviour of an AndroidWearableService or whether some external factors are at play (I am using an xperia z5)

Answer (score 0):

The send message does not gaurantee the message will be delivered. I would suggest you try data api. and monitor the changes through onDatachanged